# Error occurs after uploading my website on a free web hosting

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I get the following error when accessing to the database (regdb) created on free web hosting `www.biz.nf`.

```
Access denied for user 'regdb'@'83.125.22.210' (using password: YES)
```

The website perfectly works on my computer using a localhost (through Xampp server). However, after importing my database to `biz.nf` I got that error :(

Has anyone faced such a error before? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does the user exist with that password? You only imported the applications database, the users and credentials are stored elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you Kallum for quick response. How do I know if this user exists?

Comment: Go into PHP MyAdmin and go to the Users tab along the top. Make sure you create the user "regdb" and use the password that you used on your local machine.

Comment: I exported the database from my localhost and imported it using phpmyadmin in the web hosting.

Comment: Yes but that import won't include your MySQL users. You will have to recreate the "regdb" user in the web hosting PHPMyAdmin control panel.

Comment: Thank you Kallum. But I don't see Users tap in PHPmyAdmin in the free web hosting !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74937/discussion-between-user41959-and-kallum-tanton).

Comment: We don't know 1) how exactly you're *trying* to connect to that database or 2) how exactly you *should* be connecting to that database. There's little we can do to help you here as it is. You should probably be contacting your host instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this before, the problem is the password is incorrect. I was so sure it was right when I did it, but then i clicked forgot password, and it sent me an email and I realised it was incorrect. also, i suggest you try using this website - [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/854819.html) they have amazing service and are up 99% of the time.